# Magento2: How to redirect user from cart page to any other page?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.5-p1

I have a magento site in ver 2.3.5-p1

I want to redirect `/checkout/cart/` this page to homepage, because my site is Quote only store and so no need of normal cart page. For that I have created a module to override `Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Index` this controller. Then added following code in my new controller:

```
namespace MyCompany\RedirectShoppingCart\Controller\Cart;

class Index extends \Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Index
{
    /**
     * Shopping cart display action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        return $this->_response->setRedirect('/quotation/quote/', 301);
    }
}
```

But this is giving following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Amazon\Login\Plugin\CartController::afterExecute() must implement interface Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface, 
instance of Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor given, called in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php on line 146 and defined in /var/www/html/vendor/amzn/login-with-amazon-module/Plugin/CartController.php:44
```

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> because my site is Quote only store and so no need of normal cart page.

Based on your statement above - I'm assuming that you DONT need/leverage the Amazon modules that ship OOTB with Magento 2.3.5.

If that is a valid assessment, your simplest option would be to disable the following Amazon modules:

1. Amazon_Login
2. Amazon_Core
3. Amazon_Payment

And this can be achieved - via the CLI - using the following commands:

```
bin/magento module:disable Amazon_Login
bin/magento module:disable Amazon_Core
bin/magento module:disable Amazon_Payment
```

Good Luck!

Cheers,

**Sharath**

Comment: Hi Sharath, thanks for the answer, but is it possible to do without disabling those modules? As I don't want to make any major change sin site, instead just add that simple redirect. Please check and advise?

Answer (score 1):

You can disable this plugin.
File di.xml

```
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Index">
        <plugin name="amazon_login_cart_controller" disabled="true" />
    </type>
```